# Did they goof mixing Warehouse 13 and Eureka universes?

Tags: sy-fy, warehouse-13, eureka

So, I've been watching Warehouse 13, and I've seen at least 3 episodes with actors from Eureka in the show. Of these, the first 2 had the same actors with different people, the last had the same actor acting as the same person. What this an oversight, or is there some in-universe explanation for why the previous actors were acting differently?

Comment: I'm curious to know what episodes these are

Comment: The two episodes with the same actors in different roles: [Episodes 1.8 and 1.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warehouse_13_%28season_1%29). Fargo in the Warehouse is [episode 2.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warehouse_13_%28season_2%29)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't notice those at the time - I wouldn't really call it a goof though unless they had Neil Grayston playing another character, THEN had him in as Fargo... the ones that appeared in S1 don't (and I suspect won't) appear as their Eureka characters.

Comment: Well, there was an episode of Eureka where Claudia is on Eureka, so it adds a bit more to the mix, but... ([Episode 4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Eureka_episodes))

Comment: Take a look at Episode 1.5 of Eureka, I forgot about that one...

Comment: Interesting... That would still be in universe, so...

Comment: My guess would be that the non-crossover use of the Eureka cast members was a simple business decision to draw viewers of the established show Eureka to watch the then new show of Warehouse 13 to boost ratings.

Comment: @badgerr Saul Rubenick plays a guest star in a "crisis-of-the-week" episode of Eureka. This particular episode was not a crossover. http://eureka.wikia.com/wiki/Invincible

Comment: In the original Star Trek, the Romulan commander in "Balance of Terror" and Sarek in "Journey to Babel" were both played by Mark Lenard; they're clearly not the same character. Actors commonly play multiple roles.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Eureka, Warehouse 13, and apparently Alphas, all exist in the same universe.  This is supported by a number of cross-over episodes, namely Warehouse 13 S2E5: 13.1, S3E6: Don't Hate the Player, and Eureka S4E5: Crossing Over.  Each episode makes explicit reference to established facts in the other series.  From those three episodes, it's clear that Warehouse 13 and Eureka inhabit the same universe.  The proof for Alphas existing in the same universe is much less convincing.  In S1E5: Never Let Me Go, Lindsay Wagner reprises her role from Warehouse 13 as Dr. Vanessa Calder, although no mention of the Warehouse is made (albeit for the obvious reason that it's a secret).  On a side note, a huge opportunity to tie Alphas to Eureka was missed in Alphas S1E7: Catch and Release, but that's not important.

In at least 2 different episodes of Warehouse 13, there are references that the Warehouse is "not Eureka" or that some aspect belongs in Eureka, not the Warehouse.

As for actors in Eureka or Warehouse 13 appearing in the other series as another character, that's because there's a limited amount of acting talent in Vancouver, and Eureka and Warehouse 13 use the same casting directors, so when they see someone they like for a minor role, they're probably going to call them back before a casting call.  This isn't the first time this has happened either: Star Trek (Jeffrey Combs appeared in 3 different series as 3 different characters.  Marc Alaimo, best known for his portrayal as Gul Dukat in DS9, not only played a *different* Cardassian in TNG, but 3 other characters in TNG as well.  Other examples abound.), Stargate (Brandy Ledford played a Tok'Ra in SG1 and a planet-of-the-week inhabitant in Atlantis as an example, there are many more), the list goes on.  This happens a lot in TV, and it's not restricted to sci-fi.  There are examples from many other genres as well.

Comment: also in the alpha's episode dr calder was wearing the trademark purple gloves from wh13

Comment: Jeffrey Combs even did [two](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Brunt) of his [characters](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Weyoun) in the [same episode](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Dogs_of_War_(episode))

Comment: @user3021 Purple Nitrile gloves are typically worn by science personnel. The Nitrile gloves are also a bit more resistant to corrosive/acidic chemicals and other hazardous substances. Also, they tend to be used as an alternative to Latex gloves, since some people are allergic to Latex. They aren't trademarked to Warehouse 13 specifically. They have shown up in procedural cop shows too.

Comment: Can you please addd a bit more details of "Each episode makes explicit reference to established facts in the other series." - what ARE those facts?

Comment: Michael Dorn played a character in Star Trek 6 (Colonel Worf) before playing Lt. Commander Worf in TNG.

Comment: To be pedantic, although Colonel Worf predated Lt. Worf within the Star Trek universe, Dorn first appeared in TNG as Lt. Worf in 1987 before he played Colonel Worf in Star Trek VI in 1991.

Answer (score 7):

In universe: They're different characters who just happen to look alike.

Out of universe: Warehouse 13 and Eureka are both produced by the same company, and perhaps there's some synergy going on with casting.  In addition, sci-fi shows often share actors, with actors from one sci-fi show working on other sci-fi shows (e.g. Summer Glau).  This is even true within franchises.  Some of the cast members in Stargate:Atlantis and Stargate:Universe played different characters in minor, one-episode roles in SG-1, in a fashion similar to the W13/Eureka actors in your question.

Comment: In Stargate:Atlantis Jewel Staite actually played a hybrid Wraith in "Instinct" and then later came back as a totally different character in seasons 4 & 5...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a real "in-universe" explanation.

Out-of-universe, it's a common scenario in Sci-Fi to have actors appear in other series - aside from Keen-mentioned StarGate crossovers, there's the (in)famous "Jason X"/"Andromeda" one.

In "Jason X", Lexa Doig's Dr. Rowan had an android KM14, played by Lisa Ryder - which was a (likely intentional?) gag based on the fact that Lexa Doig played an android Romy in TV Sci-Fi series "Andromeda" together with Lisa Ryder's Beka Valentine character.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the shows for SyFy are all shot in Toronto and Vancouver and you will see a great deal of actor crossover between all the various shows. Sometimes they're playing their character from the other show, sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

Global dynamics is the main research facility in eureka, where Fargo works.  Warehouse 13 is another secret facility in America. Fargo came and installed some computers in the warehouse and later claudia from the warehouse came to eureka and farted about with Fargo.

There is nothing complicated about their coexistence, two government operated depts both dealing with some freaky shit.

Answer (score -2):

It may not be an oversight but rather a delayed idea as not all crossovers are planned from day one

Simply put eureka and warehouse 13 weren't in the same world originally but were merged to spark cross following interest
E.g eureka viewers may never watch warehouse 13 due to lack of interest till Claudia visits

Comment: Welcome for SF&F:SE. I'm pretty sure Eureka, WH13, Alphas were **always** intended to be in the same "Syfy-verse"